# XNA Windows Phone Simulator on 'Mac-Windows' vs. regular Windows

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, emulation

I installed my .net stuff recently on a Mac, i.e. preinstalled a version of Windows 7 before using Bootcamp. Does anyone have an explanation, why the Windows Phone 7 Simulator is so slow, compared to a Simulator installed on a 'regular' Windows system when deploying a target onto it?

Comment: Deplaying?  Do you mean displaying?  Deploying?

Comment: Debriefing - "Our plan of attack..."

Comment: Are you running Windows in a virtual machine, like VM Ware Fusion or Parallels Desktop?

Comment: I do some of my Windows Phone 7 on a MacBook pro with Windows 7 in bootcamp (not parallels, it doesn't really work on paralells), and it's a little slow, but partially because the laptop is a few years old. If you're running it in a VM, you'll have horrible performance (if you can even get it to work). You said you used bootcamp, but what do you mean you preinstalled a version *before* using bootcamp?

Comment: deploying ---- DEPLOYING!!!! :)

Comment: I shoud have taken more time, explaining this: So I installed Windows 7 (OEM - does that matter?) on my Macbook Pro with Bootcamp. Then I installed all the Software necessary, in order to start making Windows-Phone 7 Apps. The thing is, when I try to put an App onto the Simulator, it takes like at least 2 minutes, to do this. It seems rather long compared to 2-3 seconds, to deploy a target on a not-on-a-mac Windows 7 OS....

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem when i run the xna app meant for xbox as a windows program.

Answer (score 1):

Performance overhead might be caused because of the non-nativity of the hardware platform you are running it on. The emulator itself has a set of [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) - if these aren't met then you should expect serious drops in performance and stability (in case it starts).

Answer (score 0):

When you're comparing the performance "Regular Windows", do you mean on another machine (PC)? If so, it could be down to hardware differences - (Graphics card, processor speed, less RAM, slower hard disk).

It could also be down to drivers - I don't know much about the Mac hardware, but it's possible Windows drivers aren't as good for hardware that's more commonly used by Macs.